# Bug in my datagridview EditingControlShowing handler (.NET)

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and a handler for the EditingControlShowing event which is used to add or remove handlers for the keyUp event for some columns. The problem is sometimes a column which does not have an associated  KeyUp handler actually fires the handler. It seems like the grid does not know which column is supposed to fire which handler.

Problem: When I type in column2 (not column1), the line which removes the KeyUp handler runs.. so far so good. But then the Control_KeyUp runs! Control_KeyUp is only for Column1.

Is there a way to find out if a column (or cell?) has handlers attached to it?

```
    private void  MyGrid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
  {
   string columnName = MyGrid.Columns[MyGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name;
   if (columnName == "column1")
        e.Control.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyUp);
    else
        e.Control.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(Control_KeyUp);
    ......

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's similar question you may find useful:

[EditingControlShowing events firing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582625/editingcontrolshowing-events-firing-multiple-times)

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx):

> When attaching event-handlers to the
>   editing control, you must therefore
>   take precautions to avoid attaching
>   the same handler multiple times. To
>   avoid this problem, remove the handler
>   from the event before you attach the
>   handler to the event. This will
>   prevent duplication if the handler is
>   already attached to the event, but
>   will have no effect otherwise.

Hope some of this helps.

Comment: I read the MSDN article. The keyword was that for the same type of column, the same Editingconrol is used. So if the editing control already has a handler, it will fire for ANY column using that editing control. So removing the handler before adding a new one was the answer.